# How do I get the second Sun Stone in level 2-4?

Tags: kirby-triple-deluxe

I have tried this level 4 times over now and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the second Sun Stone in level 2-4.  I think it might have something to do with the Ninja ability, but I am not sure.

How do I get this Sun Stone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll eventually get to a room with many doors. After your first two successful doors, you should enter a room with a door to your right and a banner where a door should be on your left.

The left banner should have a hole in it, though it'll look like part of the background. That hole is actually a door, and you go in there to get the sun stone.